# how to communicate to a reverse tunnel on the host machine from a docke container?

Tags: docker, networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel, docker-network

I have this setup:

```
docker container (running caddy) -> ec2 host machine -> reverse tunnel -> local machine
```

The idea is to roll my own ngrok. This was working with nginx running on the host machine but since moving to caddy has been broken.

I tunnel from my local machine to the EC2 instance like this:

```
ssh -R 9000:0.0.0.0:3000 -N lab
```

I can confirm the tunnel works by doing `curl localhost:9000` on the EC2 machine.

The container communicates to the host machine using `172.17.0.1:9000`, which works if I'm running a process directly on the host machine.

How do I connect the container to a reverse tunnel on the host machine?

This is NOT a duplicate issue of a simple communication to the host machine using host.docker.internal. I'm already doing that and confirmed the communication works but this is a more specific case